# How to uninstall iOS app using command shell in jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, shell, jailbreak

I want to uninstall iOS app via shell in jailbroken iPhone in batches.
In my mind just use

```
rm -rf ${path/to/sandbox}..........
```

but after doing this in the shell, the icon of the app which I want installed still exists in *springboard*. Would be anything else should be remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you are using a simple `rm` command to delete your app. You then notice that after removing the `.app` folder, you still see an app **icon** on your SpringBoard. Right?

The solution to this is simply to force SpringBoard to refresh its list of apps. You can do this at the command line (on the phone) with:

```sh
su mobile -c uicache
```

The `uicache` command, run as user `mobile` will update the list of applications. After a few seconds, you'll see the app icon disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,that is the right method what i want found,with this i can uninstall app in batches,nothing can express my thanks ,with a gift for you ~~  https://github.com/pandazheng/IosHackStudy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete an application downloaded from the App Store you can do so right in the Springboard (on your iPhone). If you can't do that, you can delete it in the folder `(/private)/var/mobile/Applications/`. That's where apps are installed from the App Store or synced. (in `/Applications/` you will find Cydia, Camera, Safari, etc...)

To do so, you will first have to find out what is the "hashed" name of the Applications in that folder, because you won't find `InfinityBlade.app` in there, you will find some random letters and numbers.

You can also delete it by installing a program called iFile from the Cydia and then by checking in the settings "Show application names" or something like that and then again by going to `(/private)/var/mobile/Applications/` where you should see now the real name of the applications and then simply delete it by the gesture "slide from left to right with your finger" and click delete.

Hope this works for you, it should work 100% ;-)

This is a link to a video which sort of describes what I meant with iFile, just don't go into `/var/stash/Applications` but `/var/mobile/Applications`:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftssbPYiBDw

Comment: Thanks for your answare,I've got another way to realize my thinking,a command line tool run in mac OS name is "ideviceinstaller",I can got Bunddle ID for all the App I installed  by shell ,and use ssh login mac ,do " ideviceinstaller -u ${Bunddle ID} ${UUID}" can uninstall App by batches.